# MySQL server on Ubuntu fails to start after changes made to my.cnf in Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows, mysql, services

I have MySQL 5.5 running on Ubuntu Server 12.10. When I run `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`, I get the following:

```
mysql start/running, process 2754
```

However, when I open /etc/mysql/my.cnf in Windows via a Samba share and save the file without any changes, I get the following when running the exact same command, `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

What is causing the mysql from restarting? How can I make edits in windows without breaking my config file?

Answer (score 2):

It could it be Windows line endings vs Unix line endings?

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in Windows but you have to use other editor than Notepad. Try Notepad++, PsPad or similar software. Windows notepad always change line endings to Windows style and it causes problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dos2unix` tool to convert the line endings to the unix format:
`$ sudo apt-get install dos2unix`
`$ dos2unix /path/to/my.cnf`

and see if this fixes the issue, now that its done.
Probably when you opened the file with `notepad` or some other editor, it asked you to convert the line endings to windows compatible and you selected yes.

Answer (score 0):

As you running MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu Server 12.10,
1st Check the process is running or not with below command.

```
ps aux |grep mysql
```

if running Kill the PID like its showing `mysql start/running, process 2754` and try to start the MySQL again. Check if tis installed or not with this command `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql` if it's listed as installed, you got it. Else you need to install it and Finaly check the pid path in my.cfg default is `/var/lib/mysql` after killing the process remove the sock file.

As you said "you opened my.cnf in Windows via a Samba share and save the file without any changes" it doesn't matter if u didnt changed anything it ll not effect MySQL.